# How to use a different distribution for rate transitions in a statechart?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'd like to use a different distribution for defining the transition probabilities in the statechart of an agent. I know that AnyLogic uses the exponential distribution as the default distribution for rate triggered transitions, but on occasion other distributions are more fitting, such as in the case of a disease statechart where often the weibull or gompertz distribution is used.

How would I go about implementing this? Obviously, just directly inputting a weibull distribution as the rate does not work. Would I need to define a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a rate triggered transition, you are forced to use the exponential distribution. Something you can do instead is using a dynamic event and trigger with message. The following example shows how to create the dynamic event.

[image: StateChart Example]

Then the action in the dynamic event is

```
statechart.fireEvent("message");
```

You can do the same with any distribution you want. But you don't have all the distributions available, for the gompertz distribution, you have to create your own function to generate random samples.

Comment: How would I use this approach if there are multiple transitions possible, each with different probabilities?

Comment: the same way... you produce different dynamic events and the one that happens first will be the one generating the transition... the others will have no effect if the message doesn't correspond to the message associated with the possible transitions

Comment: Unfortunately this approach or my implementation of this approach does not work as well as anticipated. All agents end up in their final states shortly after running the model. An illustration model can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufrffowultqf6qu/Model1.alp?dl=0

Comment: are you serious? You are using:
create_DEdeathOtherCauses(uniform(0, 0.004)); 
which means that the transition will happen in 0.004 seconds... What did you expect?
to use minutes or something else you have to do:
create_DEdeathOtherCauses(uniform(0, 0.004),MINUTE);

Comment: that means that the probability of moving directly to "Dying from other causes" is like 97% or something... You need to think better what you are doing, review the help documentation of anylogic, and not give up as soon as it doesn't work

Comment: Even with model time set to days and specifying the time after the distribution with create_DE, I can't seem to get the distribution right: all the dynamic events fire far too quickly. To clarify: I want the weekly probability to transit from state1 to state2 to be drawn from a distribution, for example uniform distribution. For example, from uniform(0,0.1) a value of 0.05 is drawn, and this should then be the weekly/yearly/daily probability to transit from state1 to state2.

Comment: if you change the model time to days, years or centuries.. it will be the same... you have to keep it in seconds, and use HOUR as I showed in the example... and since your timings are so slow, if you use HOUR, it will take 10  seconds to transition to death in general. Download your new model here:
https://ufile.io/4ndmi
About your distributions, I don't know and I don't want to think about it